# Why do I keep getting "vector subscript out of range" error for 2D vector?

Tags: c++, adjacency-list, indexoutofrangeexception, 2d-vector

I am trying to create an adjacency list graph representation using a vector(V) of vectors(v). My goal is for every new vertex value entered, I increment the size of the V*, and insert the new value into the open spot, which would then be the starting value of v**.

I then want to create an edge between the new value entered, and another value that already exists in the adjacency matrix.

However, with my code I keep getting the "vector subscript out of range error" once I enter the secIndexVal. I've already tried making the initial value of numberIndices larger (up to 10) as well as the things I've mentioned in the code. Thank you.

*The Vector of vectors, I notated as 'V'
**A vector within V, I notated as 'v'

```
int indexVal; 
int secIndexVal; 
int numberIndices = 0; 
bool valIsFound = false; 
vector <vector <int>> vecOfVectors(numberIndices);

int main()
{
    cout << "\nEnter first value: ";
    cin >> indexVal;

    cout << "\nEnter second value: ";
    cin >> secIndexVal;

    numberIndices++;
    vecOfVectors.resize(numberIndices);
    vecOfVectors[numberIndices - 1].push_back(indexVal);
    vecOfVectors[numberIndices - 1].push_back(secIndexVal);
    //pushes back the values of indexVal then secIndexVal to index 0 
    //I tried changing the value within the brackets to [numberIndices]

    numberIndices++;
    vecOfVectors.resize(numberIndices);
    vecOfVectors[numberIndices].push_back(secIndexVal); 
    vecOfVectors[numberIndices].push_back(indexVal);
    //pushes back the values of secIndexVal then indexVal to index 1
    //I tried changing the value within the brackets to [numberIndices + 1]         

    cout << "\nExit? (y/n)";
    cin >> userPrompt;

    while (userPrompt != 'y')
    {

        cout << "\nEnter a new value: ";
        cin >> indexVal; //new value

        numberIndices++;
        vecOfVectors.resize(numberIndices); 

        cout << "\n enter a value to connect it to: ";
        cin >> secIndexVal; //old value

        vecOfVectors[numberIndices - 1].push_back(indexVal); //new value given newly opened spot on vecOfVectors


        for (int j = 0; j < numberIndices; ++j)
        {
            if (vecOfVectors[j].at(0) == secIndexVal)
            {
                valIsFound = true; 
                vecOfVectors[j].push_back(indexVal); //the new value is attached to the adjacency list at the index of the old value
            }
        }

        if (valIsFound == true)
        {
            vecOfVectors[numberIndices - 1].push_back(secIndexVal); //the old value is attached to the adjacency list at the index of the new value
        }

        cout << "\nExit? (y/n)";
        cin >> userPrompt;
    }
}
```

Comment: `vecOfVectors.resize(numberIndices); vecOfVectors[numberIndices].push_back(secIndexVal);` Are you missing the -1 here? Use the debugger. When you get an error walk up the call stack to your code and you can see exactly where and why you're getting an error. If you always want the last item in the vector consider using the [back()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/back) function.

Comment: What is the value of the index that triggers this error?